# Looking for a lightweight solution to systematically instrument the if-conditions of C functions

Tags: python, c, instrumentation

I need to use lightweight instrumentation tools (say, using some existing Python or maybe C pre-processor framework) to systematically insert statements in if-conditions of C functions:

For example, let foo be the C function:

```
int foo(int x){
   if (x>3) 
        return x;
}
```

I need to transform it to

```
int foo(int x){
   if (x>3){ 
        print ("%d", x); 
        return x;
  }
}
```

I have tried using LLVM, but it does not integrate better with other parts of the code. Here, I would prefer a Python/C preprocessor framework solution. Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: A `void` function cannot return a value. And even if it was `int` type, not all your paths return a value.

Comment: What have you tried?  And exactly how automatic do you want this to be -- are you willing to manually add anything to these `if` statements?

Comment: In your example, the code to be inserted seems fairly specific to the context into which you want to insert it.  How do you imagine this being accomplished by an automated tool?

Comment: https://github.com/eliben/pycparser - parse the C code.  Navigate the AST, and add your own customization as you walk the nodes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) or perhaps the [GCC Python Plugin](https://gcc-python-plugin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to customize the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler to transform its Gimple representation. It would be a complete solution, but I am not sure it qualifies as "lightweight" (because you need to understand the details of GCC internals), but neither is a Clang/LLVM approach. You'll probably need more than a week of work (notably to learn about the internals of GCC, or of Clang/LLVM)

BTW, your problem is less easy than what you believe, since

```
int foobar(int x) { return (x>3)?(x*6):(x*x); }
```

contains a conditional. Also, your original function is *exactly* equivalent to

```
int foo(int x){
    while (x>3) // this while is done 0 or 1 time
      return x;
}
```

and it is easy to find many other ways to express it.

So a purely syntactic approach would never work completely. Hence, you cannot hope for something "light".

<sup>(my opinion is that C code instrumentation is *never* a lightweight problem)</sup>

Comment: Indeed, it looks heavier than llvm. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not heavier, but just different. You need to dive into compiler internals anyway. The point is that `if` statement does not mean much (you can have conditional in other forms)